# Mule ESB HTTP post with JSON body

Tags: json, http, post, mule

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do an HTTP POST with a JSON in a request body.  A sample of my flow is posted below.  I have a poller that polls a POJO, which generates a JSON when it is polled.  I then need to take this JSON and do an HTTP POST with it in the body to an external REST service.  The Apache HTTP Client equivalent would be to set a string entity to my JSON message and set the header content type to application/json.  How would I do this in Mule? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
    <poll frequency="100000">
        <logger message="starting" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </poll>
    <component class="JavaJSONGeneratorClass" doc:name="ReferenceToJavaClass"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="8080" path="path/to/service" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

And the Java class would do something like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.mule.module.client.MuleClient;

public class JSONGenerator implements Callable, Serializable 
{

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception 
{

    String json = generateSomeJson(some_parameter);

    return json;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably only forgetting to set the contentType attribute to your http outbound endpoint that should look like the following:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="8080" path="path/to/service" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json"/>
```

Also mule comes with OOTB solutions for Json such as the [object-to-json-transformer](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Native+Support+for+JSON) or 
[DataMapper](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/DataMapper+Transformer+Reference) for the EE version, so I would recommend the use one of those rather than a custom one whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the http method, try with this:

`<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="8080" path="path/to/service" doc:name="HTTP" method="POST"/>`